# bourne shell if [ -e $directory/file.$suffix ]

Tags: shell, solaris, test, bourne-shell

```
#!/bin/sh
CONFIG_DIR="/var/opt/SUNWldm/"
read option
if [ $option -eq 9 ]; then
        ret=1
elif [ -e ${CONFIG_DIR}file.xml.${option} ]; then
        echo "TRUE"
fi
```

I have the above code in a while loop to present a list of options. Unfortunately I'm having problems with the `elfi` statement.

> From: [IF for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) the -e returns true if the file exists.

I've double checked the syntax and even running the script in debug mode (I put `set -x` at the beginning of this script and could see that the replacement in the `if` is done properly as seen inline:

```
+ [ 201301271355 -eq 9 ]
+ [ -e /var/opt/SUNWldm/file.xml.201301271355 ]
./ldm_recover.sh: test: argument expected
```

I've been searching so far and haven't found a reason for failing, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: On Solaris, don't use `/bin/sh`, use `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` to  get a standard shell. `/bin/sh` is only for backward compatibility for old scripts that rely on `/bin/sh` being a Bourne shell and not a standard `sh`.

Comment: I need to maintain what is already previously being use and that sticks me to /bin/sh or perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Bourne shell is somewhat of an antique. The Solaris version doesn't have the `-e` operator for the `test` (a.k.a. `[`) builtin that was introduced somewhat late in the life of the Bourne shell¹ and enshrined by POSIX.

As a workaround, you can use `-f` to test for the existence of a regular file, or `-r` if you aren't interested in unreadable files.

Better, change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/ksh` so as to get a POSIX shell.

Beware that `[ $option -eq 9 ]` is probably not right: `-eq` is a numerical comparison operator, but `$option` isn't really numeric — it's a date. On a 32-bit machine, when `201301271355` is interpreted as a number, it is taken modulo 2<sup>32</sup>. It so happens that no date in the 21st century is very close to 0 modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, but relying on this is very brittle. Make this `[ "$option" = 9 ]` instead.

As a general shell programming principle, **always put double quotes around variable and command substitutions**: `"$foo"`, `"$(foo)"`. If you don't, the shell splits the result at each whitespace character and treats each resulting word as a filename wildcard pattern. So an unprotected `$foo` is only safe if the value of `foo` does not contain any whitespace or `\[?*`. Play it safe and always use double quotes (unless you intend the splitting and pattern matching to happen).

¹  <sub>Or was it a ksh addition never ported to Bourne? I'm not sure.</sub>

Comment: Thanks @Gilles for the recommendation and the effort explaining it. But in this case, the $option is indeed a integer that is taken from the files names, presented in a menu and then given "copy/paste" or insert manually in the read option. I'll update the script with the '"' so I don't get surprises if a user makes a mistake with spaces. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well this was easier than I though:

It seems that the `-e` operator for the `if` is not defined in bourne shell (sh) but only in bourne again shell (bash).

I replaced the `if [ -e ...` by `if [ -r ...` and it's working.

Comment: The [standard test command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html) supports the `-e` flag, and that command is what standard `sh` should support. Your answer is not correct for `sh` in general, but only very old nonstandard `sh`s on Solaris.

Comment: @kojiro you will notice that I'm using #!/bin/sh, do the answer is indeed correct for this environment, I could agree if I would be using the other sh available like /usr/xpg4/bin/sh.